# How to compute the average aligned ranks of variables from Friedman's test

Tags: r, post-hoc, friedman-test

In the paper [EUSBoost: Enhancing ensembles for highly imbalanced data-sets by evolutionary undersampling](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2013.05.006), in figure 2 and 3, the average aligned ranks of methods being compared are plotted.

Can anyone help with how to get the average aligned ranks of variables from Friedman's test? I'd also appreciate some direction on how to do a holm post-hoc test in R.

Comment: Should anyone have similar issues, the scmamp library in R worked, the rankMatrix function in particular.